# Update FileField value in instance Django Model save method

Tags: python, django, django-models

What is the best way the update the total field with value total the rows the file?
Implement in model or views or other? How to make The file registration will always be through django-admin

models.py

```
class Registry(models.Model):

   file_upload = models.FileField(blank=True, null=False) #csv or xlsx
   total = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, default=None)

   def save(self):
     with open(self.file_upload) as f:
        self.total = sum(1 for line in f)
        return self.total
```

Error:

```
 TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not FieldFile
```

Comment: Did you try  `open(self.file_upload.path)` or `open(self.file_upload.url)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply read the file content of the uploaded file as using `.read()` method.

And then do whatever you want to do with that content.

```
def save(self):
    self.total = sum(1 for line in self.file_upload.read())
    super(Registry, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

No need to again open at OS level.

Comment: How to display value and file in interface django-admin? After saving the registration in django-admin the file does not appear, nor the value in the total field

Comment: @LidyMonteiro, can you check the updated code and see if the above works ? You had forgot to call `save()` method.

Answer (score 1):

The output of `self.file_upload` is a *FieldFile* object. You should change it to `self.file_upload.path` where will give you the string path of file.

And to makesure your `self.file_upload` is not None/Null, you should validate it also.

```
def save(self):
    if self.file_upload:
        with open(self.file_upload.path) as f:
            ....
```

You can read this docs for more https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/files/#using-files-in-models

Answer (score 0):

I generally choose model part if I need to use the method for most of the instances that will be created. But in this case, I probably choose Django Forms to handle this business logic. By the way, you can choose all the possibilities. At least you can achieve what you need in both cases. If the business logics changes very often, I can suggest to move these logics to views or forms.
The error you have encountered is about open statement, which requires one of the types that declared in error message. To achieve that, you can change `self.file_upload` to `self.file_upload.path` which is the path that file uploaded. I strongly recommend you to use csv module or an excel file library to handle file read operations.